# Why am I getting near "INTEGER": syntax error?

Tags: python, sql, database, syntax-error

In a certain function, I'm making a table within a database, but for this bit of code:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE count(value1 TEXT, value2 INTEGER')
```

I'm getting a "near "INTEGER": syntax error". Any idea what's causing the problem

Comment: What database? Check your parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't complete your SQL syntax and you missed a closing parenthesis there.

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE count(value1 TEXT, value2 INTEGER)') 
                                                           ^
```

Comment: Thanks! I should start using this sit more often.